# Revit ActiveAddInId Statement error

Tags: revit

this is the statement that i thought should work:

commandData.Application.ActiveAddInId;

Error: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing that because you're not assigning the value to a variable. The Active AddInId variable is just a string representing a GUID, so it can't be called as a statement.

What are you trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to retrieve the Id of an addin you should create a variable and then assign the `AddinId` property. According the to the revit API documention the `ActiveAddInId` variable is of the class `AddInId`. So your code should look something like this.

```
AddInId id = commandData.Application.ActiveAddInId;
```